# Validar Eliminacion de Registros relacionados MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework

Soy nuevo en MVC, quisera saber como puedo validar que al momento de borrar un registro padre me muestre un mensaje donde le indique al usuario que no se puede borrar por la relacion con los registros hijos.

Tengo una validacion en el create POST de mi controlador el cual es el siguiente:

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AreaId,NameArea")] Area area)
    {
        if (db.Area.Any(a => a.NameArea == area.NameArea))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("NameArea", "Ya existe una Área con este nombre.");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Area.Add(area);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(area);
    }
```

Quisiera hacer la validación del borrado similiar a la anterior, o si hubiera alguna otra forma lo agradeceria.

Comment: `Area` tiene una Colección de hijos?

Comment: Si una colección  llamada Distritos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar la validacion cuando eliminas ya que pasas el id de la entidad

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id) {

    var area = db.Area.Include(x=>x.PropRelacionada)
                        .FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id);

    if(area == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("IdArea", "No existe una Área con el ID.");
    }

    if(area.PropRelacionada.Count() > 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("xxArea", "El Area se encuentra relacionado con XX");
    }

     return View();
}
```

La idea es que si usas entity framework mapees la relacion entre las entidades, asi con el `Include()` puede recuperar si tiene una relaciona con la entidad que quieres validar

[Cargar entidades relacionadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion para este problema resulta que tenia que validar el SaveChanges() con try y catch:

```
    // POST: Areas/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Area area = db.Area.Find(id);
        db.Area.Remove(area);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null &&
               ex.InnerException.InnerException != null &&
               ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.Contains("REFERENCE"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "El registro no puede borrarse porque tiene otros registros relacionados.");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
            }

            return View(area);
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Luego en la vista Delete agregar:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

De esta forma valido las relaciones entre registros padres e hijos.